# java code completion engine

Tags: java, groovy, code-completion

When i mean `code completion` i don't mean `autocompletion`

My use case is the following:

> 1. The browser is sending an ajax request for code completion to the server (parameters to be defined),
> 2. then the server on receving this request, use an engine (the one i am asking for) to process the args and return in JSON format the result. For instance: `{completions:{"completion1":"getArg()","completion2":"setArg()"}}`
> 3. the result is displayed inside the browser.

I need to find a library that will process the code completion. The main issue is that existing engines are too tight to user interface (ie you need swing or SWT)

If there is some pointers on how to reuse eclipse or netbeans code completion engine.

Extra would be something out of the box for Groovy code completion.

Comment: I do not think that your question is clear. At least I did not understand what did you mean. Since guys have not answered you they probably did not understand too.

Comment: do you want to be able to edit json code in web based application and enjoy code completion?

Comment: What are you trying to complete? All you need is a list of completions based on the current context--what's your context?

Comment: trying to achieve groovy code completion on a browser. Each time i hit ctrl+space it sends request for code completion.

Comment: What sort of dictionary of “completions” are you looking-for? Just a set of keywords, or context-sensitive (`foo` is of type `gribble`, so `foo.<TAB>` sends an AJAX request for methods that apply to `gribble`?)

Comment: context sensitive, but anyway it should be agnostic somehow

Answer (score 0):

Search in google "web based ide".

Take a look on http://shiftedit.net/. Probably you even do not have to implement anything. Just take this or similar product.

Comment: well this is a good hint, but it does not do code completion.